# How can I allow users to create private pages?

Tags: users

I want a way to create a way to allow only specific users to see a specific page.

One page per user where one user can't see another's page.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is Drupal node access control, which is a huge subject.

The core's built-in support for node access control is rather course, and to control per-user access to view a page, you must use some sort of node access control module.  There is a [page at Drupal.org listing all node access modules](http://drupal.org/node/270000), with a capsule review of each.  I suggest you take a look at that page to see if you can find a suitable module.

One I suggest you take a closer look at, is [Flexi Access](http://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess).  It let you control access to a *single node* (page) for an *individual user*.  This, I believe, fits well with your requirements.  Many other content access modules have *content types* and/or *roles* or *groups* as their smallest unit of resolution.

Disclosure: I am the maintainer of *Flexi Access*.

Comment: please sir i want to use flexi access. can you send me your email?

Comment: Support requests and other questions related to a Drupal module is best dealt with by posting a message in the module's issue queue at Drupal.org.